# React Native (iOS) save file to directory & open with option

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile, native

I have two question;

**1)** I want to save a file on my app like screenshots above. I checked [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) and [react-native-document-picker](https://github.com/Elyx0/react-native-document-picker) libraries but they can't help me about this issue. (or I can't find these options)

- When user click to share button I want to open [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEqyo.jpg) menu.
- And when user select **Save to Files** *(Dosyalar'a Kaydet)* option I want to open [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t59d9.png) menu with file creation option *(up right corner icon)*

Is there any library for these actions? Or how can I create these modules?

---

**2)** Is there any way to add our app to 'Open with' menu? I mean let's say we have any '.txt' extension file and we want to open it with our app.

Example screenshots:

[SS_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP1kU.png)

User selects **More** *(Daha Fazla)*

[SS_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Iqs.png)

**EDIT:** The solution package is: https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share

Comment: Yes, read this blog: https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/open-file-with-app/

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was looking for [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) but your link is useful too